# "struct a a1 = {0};" different from "struct a a2 = {5};" why?

Tags: c, struct

If `struct a a1 = {0};` initializes all the elements (of different types) of a structure to zero, then `struct a a2 = {5};` should initialize it to `5`.. no?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _a {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
}a;

int main(void)
{
    a a0;
    a a1 = {0};
    a a2 = {5};

    printf("a0.i = %d \n", a0.i);
    printf("a0.j = %d \n", a0.j);
    printf("a0.k = %d \n", a0.k);

    printf("a1.i = %d \n", a1.i);
    printf("a1.j = %d \n", a1.j);
    printf("a1.k = %d \n", a1.k);

    printf("a2.i = %d \n", a2.i);
    printf("a2.j = %d \n", a2.j);
    printf("a2.k = %d \n", a2.k);

    return 0;
}
```

The uninitialized struct contains garbage values

```
a0.i = 134513937
a0.j = 134513456
a0.k = 0
```

The initialized to `0` struct contains all elements initialized to `0`

```
a1.i = 0 
a1.j = 0 
a1.k = 0
```

The initialized to `5` struct contains only the first element initialized to `5` and the rest of the elements initialized to `0`.

```
a2.i = 5 
a2.j = 0 
a2.k = 0
```

Would `a2.j` and `a2.k` always guaranteed to initialize to `0` during `a a2 = {5};` (or) is it an `undefined behavior`

OTOH, why am I not seeing all the elements of `s2` initialized to `5`. How is the `struct` initialization is done during `{0}` and how is it different when `{5}` is used?

Comment: "...should initialize it to 5.. no?!"
Short Answer: No.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reference:

**C99 Standard 6.7.8.21**

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

[EDIT]

**Static objects and implicit initialization:**

The storage duration of an object determines the lifetime of an object.
There are 3 storage durations:
static, automatic, and allocated

variables declared outside of all blocks and those explicitly declared with the static storage class specifier have **[static storage duration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03statdef.htm)**. Static variables are initialized to zero by default by the compiler.

Consider the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    static int j;
    printf("i = [%d]",i);
    printf("j = [%d]",j);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, `i` has automatic storage and since it is not explicitly initialized its value is **Undefined**.
While `j` has static storage duration and it is **guaranteed** to be initialized to `0` by the compiler.

Comment: +1 for the quote from the standard.  But for completeness, perhaps you should clarify how static objects are implicitly initialized.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, this is interesting indeed. It seems like it would be good practice to use `{}` and to never allow an 'uninitialized' struct. `struct a a3 = {};` Does that make sense?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: C allows uninitialized variables for efficiency reasons.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Note that As per the standard the initialiser list needs to be non-empty.

Comment: I think I understand that, especially on the stack (as opposed to the statically-allocated). But it might be a good default policy to use `{}`, except when one needs to optimize. "Premature optimization ..." and all that.

Comment: @Als, must be non-empty? That's a pity. I'll try to get in the habit then of using `={0}` then. But it doesn't look as pretty as `={}` .

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Done. A bit clumsily but will provide a basic understanding to new users,i hope.

Answer (score 8):

The omitted values will be always initialized to zero, because the standard says so. So you have essentially

```
struct a a1 = { 0, 0, 0 };
```

and

```
struct a a2 = { 5, 0, 0 };
```

which is of course different.

Answer (score 2):

No. In C, if your initializer list is incomplete, all missing indices will be filled with 0. So this:

```
int a[3] = {0};
int b[3] = {5};
```

effectively becomes:

```
int a[3] = {0, 0, 0};
int b[3] = {5, 0, 0};
```

This is why it seemingly works with `{0}` but fails with `{5}`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work for

```
struct x {
    int *y;
    /* ... */
};

struct x xobj = {5};
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) in GCC documentation.

Comment: Important to mention that It is a gcc specific compiler extension using which makes your code non portable across compilers.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is exactly the same in both cases.  If there are fewer initializers than there are elements in the aggregate, then the remaining elements are initialized *as though* they were declared `static`, meaning they'll be initialized to 0 or NULL.

It's just that in the first case, the explicit initializer has the same value as the implicit initializer.

If you want to initialize all the elements of your aggregate to something other than 0, then you will have to provide an explicit initializer for each of them, i.e.:

```
a a2 = {5, 5, 5};
```